# Powershell errors when the first word of my command is a variable that gets expanded

Tags: powershell

I want to test a powershell script I'm writing that contains a command with side-effects I don't want to actually occur.

In bash, I could write

```
> DO_OR_ECHO=$([ "$MY_DEBUG_FLAG" ] && echo 'echo' || echo)

> $DO_OR_ECHO my_dangerous_command args
```

but trying to do a similar construct in powershell doesn't seem to work, even if I hardcode it.

```
> $DO_OR_ECHO='echo'

> $DO_OR_ECHO my_dangerous_command args

Unexpected token 'my_dangerous_command' in expression or statement.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do it? I want a construct that will either execute a command, or simply print it (so that I can see what *would* have been executed), based on a boolean.

Comment: instead of trying t run a cmdlet inside a $Var, simply use and `if` structure to test the value of your trigger $Var.

Comment: Try 'cmd /c echo'.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  There are likely better ways to do it in powershell than relying on esoteric syntax/behaviors.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the invoke operator (&)

Comment: I don't want to just use an if because I don't just want to not run it, I also want what _would_ have been run to be echoed. This is also why $DO_OR_ECHO & my_dangerous_command wouldn't do what I want.

Comment: Look at cmdletbinding and -whatif. That's the powershell way to do what you want.

Comment: @KoryGill For the purpose of their question, I highly doubt they know or understand advanced function features.  Additionally, supporting common parameters for external executables is difficult; it'd be easier to just use `Write-Host`

Answer (score 3):

Use a *function*:

```bash
function doOrEcho() {
  $cmdLine = $args
  if ($MY_DEBUG_FLAG) { # echo
    "$cmdLine"
  } else {                # execute
    # Split into command (excecutable) and arguments
    $cmd, $cmdArgs = $cmdLine
    if ($cmdArgs) {
      & $cmd $cmdArgs
    } else {
      & $cmd
    }
  }
}
```

Then invoke it as follows:

```bash
doOrEcho my_dangerous_command args
```

**Limitations**:

- **Only works with calls to *external programs***, not to PowerShell cmdlets or functions (because you cannot relay *named* arguments - e.g. `-Path .` - that way).<sup>[1]</sup>

  - Passing the elements of an array (`$cmdArgs`) to an external program as *individual* arguments is a PowerShell technique called [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59071135/45375) for more information, which also notes the general caveat that an *empty string* cannot be passed as an argument as-is in PowerShell versions up to 7.2.x, wether passed directly or as part of an array used for splatting.
- As in your Bash solution, the **echoed command will *not* reflect the original and/or necessary quoting for *expanded* arguments**, so argument boundaries may be lost.

  - However, it wouldn't be too hard to reconstruct at least an *equivalent* command line that works syntactically and shows the original argument boundaries.

---

To demonstrate it (using a call to the `ls` Unix utility in PowerShell Core):

```bash
# Default behavior: *execute* the command.
PS> doOrEcho ls -1 $HOME
# ... listing of files in $HOME folder, 1 item per line.

# With debug flag set: only *echo* the command, with arguments *expanded*
PS> $MY_DEBUG_FLAG = $true; doOrEcho ls -1 $HOME
ls -1 /home/jdoe  # e.g.
```

---

[Kory Gill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5329137/kory-gill) points out that PowerShell has the [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) whose purpose is to *preview* operations without actually performing them.

However, `-WhatIf` is not the right solution for the task at hand:

- Only cmdlets and advanced functions can implement this parameter (based on functionality provided by PowerShell) - doing so requires quite a bit more effort than the simple function above.
- The intent behind `-WhatIf` is to show what *data* the command will operate on / what *changes* it will make to the system, whereas the intent behind the function above is to *echo the command itself*.

  - For instance, `Remove-Item foo.txt -WhatIf` would show something like this:
    `What if: Performing operation "Remove File" on Target "C:\tmp\foo.txt".`
- While you could technically still use `-WhatIf` in this use case, you'd then either have to use `-WhatIf` ad hoc to turn on echoing (`doOrEcho -WhatIf ...`) or set the `$WhatIfPreference` preference variable to `$true` - but doing so would then affect *all* cmdlets and functions that support `-WhatIf` while the variable is set; additionally, `-WhatIf` output is wordy, as shown above.

Arguably, it is `Invoke-Command`, PowerShell's generic command-invocation cmdlet, that should support `-WhatIf` as in the function above, but it doesn't.

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell has built-in magic to allow relaying even named arguments, but that only works when splatting the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) *as a whole*, i.e. with `@args`.</sup>

Comment: Why not do this a more proper way in powershell with cmdletbinding and support -whatif ?  That's why it exists.

Comment: @KoryGill: It's worth mentioning `-WhatIf`, but it's not the right tool for the job - please see my update.

Comment: Isn't splatting the arguments a better approach?  *Presumably* it handles appropriately quoting them, etc., i.e., `& $cmd @cmdArgs`

Comment: Good feedback and without knowing more about overall problem hard to know best design overall.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: You're right, it's the better choice here (answer updated), though it really only makes a difference with respect to `--%`, not with respect to quoting - please see the bottom section I've just added to the answer.