# Use a variable in PowerShell to pass multiple arguments to an external program

Tags: powershell, junit, parameter-passing, parameter-splatting

I downloaded the npm package for merge junit reports - https://www.npmjs.com/package/junit-merge.

The problem is that I have multiple files to merge and I am trying to use string variable to hold file names to merge.

When I write the script myslef like:

```
junit-merge a.xml b.xml c.xml
```

This works, the merged file is being created, but when I do it like

```
$command = "a.xml b.xml c.xml"
junit-merge $command
```

This does not work. The error is

> Error: File not found

Has anyone faced similar issues?

Comment: Try with `$command = "a.xml", "b.xml", "c.xml"` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```bash
> # WRONG
> ```
>
> `$command = "a.xml b.xml c.xml"; junit-merge $command`

results in command line `junit-merge "a.xml b.xml c.xml"`<sup>[1]</sup>, i.e. it **passes a string with verbatim value `a.xml b.xml c.xml` as a *single argument*** to `junit-merge`, which is not the intent.

PowerShell does *not* act like POSIX-like shells such as `bash` do in this regard: In `bash`, the value of variable `$command` - due to being referenced *unquoted* - would be subject to *word splitting* (one of the so-called [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)) and would indeed result in 3 distinct arguments (though even there an array-based invocation would be preferable).
**PowerShell supports *no* `bash`-like shell expansions<sup>[2]</sup>; it has different, generally more flexible constructs**, such as the splatting technique discussed below.

Instead, **define your arguments as individual *elements of an array***, as [justnotme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3515885/notjustme) advises:

```bash
# Define the *array* of *individual* arguments.
$command = "a.xml", "b.xml", "c.xml"

# Pass the array to junit-merge, which causes PowerShell
# to pass its elements as *individual arguments*; it is the equivalent of:
#     junit-merge  a.xml  b.xml  c.xml
junit-merge $command
```

This is an application of **a PowerShell technique called [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)**, where you specify arguments to pass to a command via a *variable*:

- Either (typically only used for *external programs*, as in your case):

  - As an ***array*** of arguments to pass individually as *positional arguments*, as shown above. In this case, even an array *literal* would work.
- Or (more typically when calling *PowerShell commands*):

  - As a ***hashtable*** to pass *named* parameter values, in which case you must **replace the `$` sigil in the variable reference with `@`**; e.g., in your case `@command`; e.g., the following is the equivalent of calling `Get-ChildItem C:\ -Directory`:
  - `$paramVals = @{ LiteralPath = 'C:\'; Directory = $true }; Get-ChildItem @paramVals`

---

**Caveat re array-based splatting**:

Due to a bug detailed in [GitHub issue #6280](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6280), **PowerShell doesn't pass *empty* arguments through to external programs** (applies to all Windows PowerShell versions / up to PowerShell (Core) 7.2.x. This **has been fixed in 7.3**, with selective exceptions on Windows, in conjunction with fixing how arguments with *embedded `"`* are passed - see the [`$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psnativecommandargumentpassing).

E.g., up to PowerShell v7.2.x, `foo.exe ""` unexpectedly results in just `foo.exe` being called.

This problem equally affects array-based splatting, so that 
`$cmdArgs = "", "other"; foo.exe $cmdArgs` results in `foo.exe other` rather than the expected `foo.exe "" other`.

The **workaround** (which also applies in v7.3+ if `$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'` is set) is to use **`'""'`** (sic).

---

**Optional use of `@` in array-based splatting with *external programs***:

As noted, with *external programs* use of `@` in lieu of `$` isn't *necessary*, because passing an array *implicitly* results in splatting.
(By contrast, when calling a *PowerShell* command to which you want to pass the elements of an array as individual, positional arguments, you *must* use `@`)

However, you may choose to use `@` with external programs too, and arguably it conveys the splatting intent more clearly:

```bash
junit-merge @command
```

There is a subtle behavioral distinction, however - though it will probably rarely if ever surface in practice:

The safer choice is to use `$`, because it guards against (the however hypothetical) accidental misinterpretation of a array element containing `--%` that you intend to be passed on as-is.

Only the `@` syntax recognizes an array element with verbatim value `--%` as the special [*stop-parsing token*, `--%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing)

Said token tells PowerShell not to parse the remaining arguments as it normally would and instead pass them through as-is - unexpanded, except for expanding `cmd.exe`-style variable references such as `%USERNAME%`.

This is normally only useful when *not* using splatting, typically in the context of being able to use command lines that were written for `cmd.exe` from PowerShell as-is, without having to account for PowerShell's syntactical differences.

In the context of *splatting*, however, the behavior resulting from `--%` is non-obvious and best avoided:

- As in direct argument passing, the `--%` is *removed* from the resulting command line.
- *Argument boundaries are lost*, so that a single array element `foo bar`, which normally gets placed as `"foo bar"` on the command line, is placed as `foo bar`, i.e. effectively as *2* arguments.

---

<sup>[1] Your call implies the intent to pass the value of variable `$command` as a *single argument*, so when PowerShell builds the command line behind the scenes, it double-quotes the verbatim `a.xml b.xml c.xml` string contained in `$command` to ensure that. Note that these double quotes are unrelated to how you originally assigned a value to `$command`.
Unfortunately, this automatic quoting is broken for values with embedded `"` chars. - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604316/45375), for instance.</sup>

<sup>[2] As a nod to POSIX-like shells, PowerShell *does* perform one kind of shell expansion, but (a) only on Unix-like platforms (macOS, Linux) and (b) only when calling external programs: Unquoted wildcard patterns such as `*.txt` are indeed expanded to their matching filenames when you call an external program (e.g., `/bin/echo *.txt`), which is feature that PowerShell calls *native globbing*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. This technique from powershell worked for me:

```
Invoke-Expression "junit-merge $command"
```

I also tried the following (from a powershell script) and it works:

```
cmd / c "junit-merge $command"
```

Comment: [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

Comment: In the case at hand, defining `$command` _as an array_   - `$command = "a.xml", "b.xml", "c.xml"` - is simpler and safer.